# Compile errors when trying to pop element from list

Tags: list, scala

I am having some strange compiler errors that I cannot seem to understand. Below is the relevant code:

```
class A {

  var x = List[B]()

  def func = {
    val temp = x(0)
    x = x tail
    temp
  }

}
```

I simply want to remove the first element from a list and return it. However, I am getting an error saying "type mismatch: found B: required Int". I cannot figure out for the life of me why it wants an Int.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the type `B`? Did you mean `Int`?

To get the first element you can use `head`. To get the rest of the list you can use `tail`. The dot operator in Scala is optional.

```
  def func = {  
    val temp = x.head
    x = x.tail
    temp
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, so for some reason, when I do x head, I get "Value update is not a member of B". And no, I want to return type B (a custom case class), but it wants an Int for some reason.

Comment: Never mind, I didn't know I needed the . for x.head. Now I have the same error with typechecker..

Comment: `x.head`, `x head`, and `x(0)` all return the first element of the list `x`. `x head` is syntactic sugar for `x.head`.

Comment: wow I am dumb. I also didn't know that you need the . for x.tail.. THANKS

Comment: For some reason you can't do x head and x tail in this context, I don't quite understand Scala syntax yet..

Comment: Try the dot notation as I noted or add parentheses. e.g. `x = (x head)` or `x = (x tail)`.

Comment: The syntax without dots was introduced to support *infix* application like `myList contains "foo"`, and works well for this. If in doubt, just write the dots.

Comment: Don't use postfix method syntax. The compiler thinks you mean `x = x tail temp`. A semicolon after tail should work as well but best to use a dot. https://mobile.twitter.com/odersky/status/49882758968905728